# Multiply array of n 3x3 rotation matrices with 3d array of 3-vectors

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have a 3d array of position vectors p [np.shape(p) yields (Nx, Ny, Nz, 3)] and an array Rn of n rotation matrices [np.shape(R) yields (n, 3, 3)].

I am trying to get an array PR of shape (n, Nx, Ny, Nz, 3) where the i-th (0 < i < n) entry at dimension 0 is the 3d array of position vectors p rotated by the 3x3 rotation matrix at index i of array Rn.

```
theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, np.pi/50)
phi = np.arange(0, np.pi, np.pi/100)

a = np.arange(100)
b = np.arange(50)
p = np.array(np.meshgrid(a, b, a, indexing="xy"))
p = np.moveaxis(p, 1, 2)
p = np.moveaxis(p, 0, 3)
# np.shape(p) => (100,50,100,3) 
Rn = np.array([np.array([np.cos(theta)*np.cos(phi), np.cos(theta)*np.sin(phi), -np.sin(theta)]),
               np.array([-np.sin(phi),              np.cos(phi),               np.zeros(np.shape(phi))]),
               np.array([np.cos(phi)*np.sin(theta), np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi), np.cos(theta)])])
Rn = np.moveaxis(Rn , 1, 2)
Rn = np.moveaxis(Rn , 0, 1)
# np.shape(Rn) => (100, 3, 3)
```

So far I have attempted the following, unsuccessfully.

```
PR= np.matmul(Rn, p)
```

What is the most efficient way to perform this operation? I know how to perform this using For loops, but in the interest of efficiency I have been trying to keep things vectorized within numpy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possible solutions are -

```
np.einsum("ijkl,nal->nijka", p, Rn, optimize=True)
td = np.moveaxis(np.tensordot(p, Rn, axes=((-1), (-1))), 3, 0)
```

I will also compare these solutions with other answers in this thread.

```
p = np.random.rand(10, 20, 30, 3)
Rn = np.random.rand(100, 3, 3)

es = np.einsum("ijkl,nal->nijka", p, Rn, optimize=True)
td = np.moveaxis(np.tensordot(p, Rn, axes=((-1), (-1))), 3, 0)
d = np.squeeze(np.moveaxis(np.dot(Rn, p[..., None]), 1, -2), -1)
out = ((Rn @ p.reshape(-1,3).T)
          .reshape(Rn.shape[0],3,-1) 
          .swapaxes(1,2)
          .reshape(-1, *p.shape)
      )

print(np.allclose(es, out))
print(np.allclose(td, out))
print(np.allclose(d, out))
```

All gives `True`.

If you try benchmarking their performance,

```
%timeit np.einsum("ijkl,nal->nijka", p, Rn, optimize=True)
%timeit np.moveaxis(np.tensordot(p, Rn, axes=((-1), (-1))), 3, 0)
%timeit ((Rn @ p.reshape(-1,3).T).reshape(Rn.shape[0],3,-1) .swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1, *p.shape))
%timeit np.moveaxis(np.squeeze(np.dot(Rn, p[..., None]), -1), 1, -1)
```

Gives,

```
3.91 ms ± 129 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.15 ms ± 168 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.45 ms ± 29.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
29.1 ms ± 98.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

For an array of the given size on my system.

`einsum` and `tensordot` seems to have comparable performance while the `@` solution seems the fastest. The `dot` solutions seems unreasonably slow though. I am not sure why since I would have imagined it's using `@` under the hood.

Comment: This is one of those cases where einsum really does shine!

Comment: Can you add my answer to your timing?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Done. But that seems to be very slow (at least in my system) and I can't am not sure why.

Comment: Weird that is so slow.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try:

```
out = ((Rn @ p.reshape(-1,3).T)
          .reshape(Rn.shape[0],3,-1) 
          .swapaxes(1,2)
          .reshape(-1, *p.shape)
      )
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do any fancy packaging since `np.dot` already takes care of the product of dimensions (unlike `np.matmul`, which broadcasts the leading dimensions together).

There are two additional steps:

1. You need to add a trailing dimension to `p` to make it the product of 3x3 by 3x1 matrices.
2. The result will have shape `(n, 3, Nx, Ny, Nz, 1)` because of the product. You will want to move the second dimension to the second to last and squeeze out the last one:

```
np.moveaxis(np.squeeze(np.dot(Rn, p[..., None]), -1), 1, -1)
```

OR

```
np.squeeze(np.moveaxis(np.dot(Rn, p[..., None]), 1, -2), -1)
```